# owncloud -problem installing packages

Tags: apt, apache2, dpkg, php, owncloud-server

I have just installed these packages for building my owncloud, but always get an installation aborted error:

```
rqie@rqie-VirtualBox:~$ sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 php5-json php5-gd php5-sqlite curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl php5-common php-xml-parser
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php5-common' instead of 'php5-json'
Note, selecting 'libcurl4-openssl-dev' instead of 'libcurl3-dev'
php-xml-parser is already the newest version.
apache2 is already the newest version.
curl is already the newest version.
libcurl3 is already the newest version.
libcurl4-openssl-dev is already the newest version.
php5 is already the newest version.
php5-common is already the newest version.
php5-curl is already the newest version.
php5-gd is already the newest version.
php5-sqlite is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 16 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up qmail (1.06-4) ...
```

The hostname -f command returned: $1

```
Your system needs to have a fully qualified domain name (fqdn) in
order to install the var-qmail packages.

Installation aborted.

dpkg: error processing qmail (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of qmail-run:
 qmail-run depends on qmail (>= 1.06-2.1); however:
  Package qmail is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing qmail-run (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 qmail
 qmail-run
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

anyone can help me ? thanks advanced

Answer (score 1):

From the logs you show with your question, you have obviously a problem with the installation of a package. But the problem is not with the packages you were asking installation : `apache2 php5 php5-json php5-gd php5-sqlite curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl php5-common php-xml-parser`.
Look at the line containing `is already the newest version`. All these packages are already installed.

The error is left by a previous tentative to install qmail which didn't succeed because of the hostname not having a fully qualified name.
As said before, setup a hostname like `host.domain.tld` by modifying `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname`.
You should have at least in `/etc/hosts` a line saying :

`<your ip>  <hostname.domain.tld> <hostname>`

If you are on a computer with dynamic IP address, use `127.0.0.1` as `<your ip>`. Or use the static ip you have received.

So you can already play around with Apache and PHP, unless the hostname problem stops Apache from working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your system needs to have a fully qualified domain name (fqdn) in
order to install the qmail packages. You probably have not set a domain, only a local hostname in /etc/hosts.  Also, a computer talks to itself using a reserved network address (usually 127.0.0.1).  In actual fact this is done via the kernel, but it still uses the networking process. More info on fdqn [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fqdn).

First you should stop the mail service using:

```
~$ service qmail stop
```

or:

```
~$ /etc/init.d/qmail stop
```

Next remove the qmail pkg completely:

```
~ $ sudo apt-get purge qmail
```

Edit /etc/hosts

```
~ $ sudo nano /etc/hosts
```

Find the line:

```
127.0.0.1 hostname
```

Change to:

```
127.0.0.1 --fqdn www.yourdomain.com hostname
```

Next reinstall the qmail packages remembering your domain set in hosts.

On next reboot check with:

```
hostname
```

`hostname -f`

This should confirm your changes.

Comment: i find 127.0.0.1 hostname , can you explain and give me example about 127.0.0.1 --fdqn www.yourdomain.com hostname . what should i fill ?

Comment: What happens when you type hostname in a terminal?

Comment: 127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       rqie-VirtualBox

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

that in my terminal, i confuse what sholud i change

Comment: You need a domain name of your own to host a mail server. You can not use a pre-existing one (such as ubuntu.com). You then need to update  etc/hosts and /etc/hostnames respectively.